# javascript equivalent to php max for arrays

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, max

I have a function in php that selects the array with that contains the most elements.

```
$firstArray = array('firstArray','blah','blah','blah');
$secondArray = array('secondArray','blah','blah');
$thirdArray = array('thirdArray','blah','blah','blah','blah');
```

then I get the name of the variable with the highest length like this:

`$highest = max($firstArray, $secondArray, $thirdArray)[0];`

but I am developing an application and I want to avoid using php and I have tried javascript's `Math.max()` to achieve the same results but it doesn't work the same way unless I do

`Math.max(firstArray.length, secondArray.length, thirdArray.length)`

But this is useless since I need to know the name of the array that contains the most elements. Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: You need to know the _name_ of the array? Or would a _reference_ to that array be enough?

Comment: @nnnnnn I need to know the name of the array

Comment: Javascript arrays don't have names...

Comment: @nnnnnn I know and thats why I add the array's name at the beginning of it so I can just do firstArray[0] and it will give me the array's name

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This function takes as input an array of arrays, and returns the largest one.

```
function largestArray(arrays){
   var largest;
   for(var i = 0; i < arrays.length; i++){
       if(!largest || arrays[i].length > largest.length){
          largest = arrays[i];
       }
   }
   return largest;
}
```

We can test it out with your example:

```
firstArray = ['firstArray','blah','blah','blah'];
secondArray = ['secondArray','blah','blah'];
thirdArray = ['thirdArray','blah','blah','blah','blah'];

// should print the third array
console.log(largestArray([firstArray, secondArray, thirdArray]));
```

Comment: this works perfectly. I was too stuck in the idea of using Math.max that I didnt even think of making another function. Thanks

Comment: +1. I was going to post the same thing, except I would've used the arguments object rather than expecting an array as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The following url has a max() equivalent. It supports more then just numbers just like in php:

[js max equivalent of php](http://phpjs.org/functions/max/)

Answer (score 0):

If you feel ok with including 3rd-party libs, maybe http://underscorejs.org/#max does what you want:

```
var aList = [firstArray, secondArray, thirdArray];
_.max(aList, function(each) { return each.length; });
```